# Python: How to set values of zero in a list/array/pd.Series to be the next non-zero value?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, sorting, pandas

I have a Python list-like structure with more than 1 million elements. Each element takes one of three possible values, namely `-1`, `0`, or `1`. What I'm trying to achieve is to replace all the zeros with the next non-zero value.

For instance, if I have

```
[1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1]
```

after the operation I'll have

[1, ***-1***, ***-1***, -1, ***1***, 1, ***-1***, ***-1***, ***-1***, -1].

I can have a nested loop structure to achieve this goal, but with more than 1 million elements in the list, it's taking forever to run. Does anyone know a faster algorithm that'll achieve this goal?

Comment: Do you need the whole output list in-memory, or would a generator approach be ok? What do you use this for downstream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try first create `Series`, then  [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) `0` to `NaN` and last use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

li = [1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1]
s = pd.Series(li)
print s
0    1
1    0
2    0
3   -1
4    0
5    1
6    0
7    0
8    0
9   -1
dtype: int64


print s.replace({0:np.nan})
0     1
1   NaN
2   NaN
3    -1
4   NaN
5     1
6   NaN
7   NaN
8   NaN
9    -1
dtype: float64
```

```
print s.replace({0:np.nan}).fillna(method='bfill')
0    1
1   -1
2   -1
3   -1
4    1
5    1
6   -1
7   -1
8   -1
9   -1
dtype: float64
```

Or instead `replace` use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html), then convert to int by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and last use [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
s.loc[s == 0] = np.nan

s.loc[s == 0] = np.nan
print s.fillna(method='bfill').astype(int).tolist()
[1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure Python solution.

Create a small class that retains the state of the prior value and compares the current value against this prior value.

```
class Checker:
    def _compare(self, val):
        if val or not self.prior:
            self.prior = val
            return val
        return self.prior
    def reverse_fill_list(self, some_list):
        self.prior = None
        return [self._compare(v) for v in some_list[::-1]][::-1]
```

Then use a list comprehension on your list in reverse order (using [::-1] to reverse).  Then reverse the results again to get back the original order.

```
some_list = [1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1]
c = Checker()  # Instantiate object.

>>> c.reverse_fill_list(some_list)
[1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1]


np.random.seed(0)
# Create one million values in range [-1, 0, 1].
a = np.random.random_integers(-1, 1, 1000000)
>>> a[:10]
array([-1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1])

%timeit c.reverse_fill_list(a)
1 loops, best of 3: 311 ms per loop
```

The result is faster using Pandas (using solution of @Jezrael).

```
>>> pd.Series(a).replace({0:np.nan}).fillna(method='bfill').tolist()
10 loops, best of 3: 136 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start iterating from the end. This would be a *O*(*n*) solution.

```
a=[0,1,0,0,0,0,-1,0];
length=len(a);
length=length-1;
//Assuming if last value is 0 you just let it be and the 0s before it.
val=0;
print a
for i in range(length):
    if (a[length-i] != 0):
        val=a[length -i];
    else:
        a[length-i]=val;
    i=i+1;
print a
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use a simple `while` loop if you want pure Python:

```
li=[1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1]
i=len(li)-1
while i:
    if li[i]:
        val=li[i]
    else:
        li[i]=val
    i-=1    

>>> li
[1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

Presumes the last value is 1 or -1, but you did not specify that the final value might trick you....